# how to consume data from rest api using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

> i am new in j query ajax.i don't have idea how to fetch data from rest API using j query ajax.  here i have created JS function to check whether passing URL working proper or not.
>   kindly help me.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$.ajax({ 
   type: "GET",
   dataType: "jsonp",
   url: "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/find-broker/ajax/search?page=1",
   success: function(data){        
     alert(data);
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: [Learning jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/). But "propertyfinder.ae" doesn't support [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Comment: that's correct.so can you guide me what can i do here?

Comment: @user3488168 you need to modify it on the server side, which is not possible

Comment: Sajeetharan. can i take data from that  url and put in separate file and same file i can call in jquery ajax function .will it work.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do a cross domain call using ajax. what you can do is to do a php call like :

```
$website = file_get_contents('http://google.com');
```

and store it in a text file and access that using your ajax on your server using the same ajax file you have.

i had similar case that i had a php call on scheduler to grab text from url every minute and update a json file. then simply use :

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
 //your function
});
```

or use ajax! whichever you fancy

Comment: Thanks In advance i will try

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is php function, and the question is not about PHP, just `jQuery` - `AJAX`.